# Groovy not showing parameters

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, continuous-deployment

I am using [Pipeline Remote Loader Plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-remote-loader-plugin) to load `.groovy` based file form git repo in my `Jenkinsfile`.

Everything works fine except parameters which is not showing when I trigger the CI job

My code for parameters looks like:

```
parameters {
  choice(choices: 'greeting\nsilence', description: 'This is test',name: 'REQUESTED_ACTION')
}
```

I expect `params.REQUESTED_ACTION` has the value of whatever use choose but it is null because the choices never displayed.

Answer (score 0):

For those who may face this, The solution was to wrap everything in `properties` so the code becomes:

```
 properties([
    parameters([choice(choices: 'env1\env2', name: 'envName', description: 'The target environment')])
])
```